# mouse hover is not working in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below **HTML** code.

```
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="Text"></input>
```

**CSS**

```
input.myButton{
    background: url("../images/button.png") no-repeat top left;
    height: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #696969;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: medium none white;
}
input.myButton:hover{
   background: url("../images/button-active.png") no-repeat top left;
   color: #FFFAF0;
}
```

But mouse hover is not working in IE7. I would like to change the image `:hover`.

How can i do this? it works fine in FireFox browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Add JS Fiddle please.

Comment: I don't have IE7 but maybe input for IE7 does not have hover state for input? Try :focus and see if it changes

Comment: IF not through CSS, is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think IE7 is so old hover doesn't work on anything but `a`. I remember this used to be a problem in IE.

You can write a workaround that uses an `onmouseover/out` listener that sets a class.

Answer (score 0):

you better use jquery because css hover support in IE varies from version to version

Comment: how can write it with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

In IE there must be declared a  `<!DOCTYPE>` for the :hover selector to work on other elements than the `<a>` element, here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

The specification for IE7 is that the :hover pseudo class will only work on the `a` tag. You can get around this by using a polyfill. I would highly recommend [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/). It allows you to use most pseudo classes on older, or unsupported, browsers.